# how to use my chrome extension to other websites

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This is the first time I am making a chrome extension so please bear with me.

I wanted to test my extension to other websites as this is somewhat a web scraper, but it seems I cannot make it work/appear on other sites. `popup.html` only appears on this website tutorial I used https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted. For others, it looks like this:
[image]
[image]

This is how it should look like at the moment
[image]

Here is my `manifest.json`

```
{
    "name": "Getting Started Example",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"],
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
    "page_action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "images/get_started16.png",
        "32": "images/get_started32.png",
        "48": "images/get_started48.png",
        "128": "images/get_started128.png"
      }
    },
    "icons": {
      "16": "images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "images/get_started128.png"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Is there a line of code I am missing? Or do I need to deploy/pack it or something? Since it's a web scraper, I need to able to test it on different sites to confirm that it will be working. Thank you.

Comment: In `manifest.json` you specify the sites that it works on.

Comment: @Barmar sorry I forgot to add it, will update my question.

Comment: Are you sure this is the manifest being used? There's nothing specifying a specific site so that it works in one place but not another is odd.

Comment: @Ouroborus yup, that is why I am wondering if maybe there are restrictions from other sites unlike the `developer.chrome.com` in which I think it allows anything. This is my first time developing one, and I can't seem to find out what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Since the latest chrome version
Now the user needs to agree that the extension is allowed for all websites..
User can do it from the
"This can read and change..." and select all websites
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNLdp.png